# WSO2 IS - Server Failed to respond on activation link

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am calling self registration using REST API of the IS. However when I click on the activation link provided in the confirmation email, the server failed to respond. Below is the error on the IS side:

```
[2018-08-09 19:27:20,816] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [confirmregistration.do] in context with path [/accountrecoveryendpoint] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /self-registration-with-verification-confirm.jsp at line 72

69:         request.getRequestDispatcher("self-registration-complete.jsp").forward(request,response);
70:     } catch (Exception e) {
71:
72:         Error errorD = new Gson().fromJson(e.getMessage(), Error.class);
73:         request.setAttribute("error", true);
74:         if (errorD != null) {
75:             request.setAttribute("errorMsg", errorD.getDescription());


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:387)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:189)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
        at org.apache.jsp.self_002dregistration_002dwith_002dverification_002dconfirm_jsp._jspService(self_002dregistration_002dwith_002dverification_002dconfirm_jsp.java:148)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

One of the example of the link generated is as below:

```
https://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx/accountrecoveryendpoint/confirmregistration.do?confirmation=e9c2d885-364c-4d39-804d-6fa5cb62ddfa&userstoredomain=PRIMARY&username=xxxxx&tenantdomain=carbon.super&callback=https://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx/publisher
```

This is how I call the create user API `/api/identity/user/v1.0/me`:

```
{
    "user": {
        "username": "myusername",
        "realm": "PRIMARY",
        "password": "password",
        "claims": [
            {
                "uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/givenname",
                "value": "kim"
            },
            {
                "uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress",
                "value": "myemail@domain.com"
            },
            {
                "uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/lastname",
                "value": "Anderson"
            },
            {
                "uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/mobile",
                "value": "+947721584558"
            }
        ]
    },
    "properties": [
        {
            "key":"callback",
            "value":"mycallbackuri"
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I missing something in the configuration? Thanks.

Comment: I just tried out the scenario and it's working. It would be better if you can share the logs.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually due to the keystore was not configured properly. if the registered CN in the keystore is different than the actual name. This will caused this issue.